# Certificate Errors, involving Python v3, and Splunk

Tags: python, certificate, splunk, self-signed

I'm working with setting up and input for Splunk 9.0.4 to pull data from an external source, I've gotten this to work on some systems, but one is giving me some problems with a certificate issue. Despite my best efforts been unable to resolve this.
This is the error
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1106)')))

I've been told it has to do with getting Python to trust the certificate, can anyone offer any insight into this? Internally all the teams I've engaged have been unable to solve this.

We have created new certs, we were able to bypass the certificate check but that is not a sustainable fix. I've engaged the Splunk support, and multiple internal teams to the company. Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer appears to be in the error message.  Replace the self-signed certificate(s) with one(s) from a CA and it should work.

Comment: We did do that, sorry if my question was not clear. The problem is how do we set a global python setting to trust our internal CA

Answer (score 0):

You need both your root and intermediates of the signing authority added into the trusted certificate store. Likely an outbound SSL decrypt in line which could also be bypassed if policy were to allow.